# How to return data from one python file to another python file

Tags: python, file, return-value

I am using a python file. I want to call another python code. Is there any way by which i can return data from 2nd python code to calling python code. Anything like function returns value to calling function.

Comment: Where's your question? This is a trivial problem (just have the called function `return` a value), so which part exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4):

I must admit I don't see the problem:

`test1.py`:

```
def myfunc():
    return "spam!"
```

`test2.py`:

```
import test1
print(test1.myfunc())
```

Output when running `test2.py`:

```
spam!
```

Answer (score 0):

Get everything into classes and functions and read a lot about [importing modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)