# Is it possible to return a value from one Python file to another?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it is possible to run another file:
    os.startfile('File.py')
and have that file return a value to the file that called the other file.

For example, you have File1. Is it possible for File1 to call and run File2 and have File2 return a value to File1?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448694/return-values-from-one-script-to-another-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230725/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-from-inside-another-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781738/how-to-return-data-from-one-python-file-to-another-python-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you running Python scripts like that? the usual way is to import one *module* ("another file") in a Python script and invoke the public functions from there. That's what the [module importing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) mechanism is for, please read the linked documentation.

As mentioned in the comments, this question has been asked before. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7448749/201359) for further help.

Comment: Thanks. I was having a brain freeze moment.

Answer (score 2):

Not with `os.startfile()`, no; it provides no way of communicating with the launched process. You could use the `subprocess` module, though; this will allow you to send data to and receive data from the launched process through standard in/out. Or, since the thing you want to call is another Python script, simply import the other file and call its functions directly, or use `execfile()`.